# I have a countdown in VB that starts with a button how do i make it start automatically when the application is opened?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my Countdown Below in `VB.net`. Does anyone know how to make it automatically start?

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        If hours_label.Text = "" Then
            hours_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If minutes_label.Text = "" Then
            minutes_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If seconds_label.Text = "" Then
            seconds_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If hours_label.Text = "00" Then
            hours_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If minutes_label.Text = "00" Then
            minutes_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If seconds_label.Text = "00" Then
            seconds_label.Text = "0"
        End If
        If seconds_label.Text > "0" Then
            seconds_label.Text = seconds_label.Text - 1
        End If
        If minutes_label.Text > "0" Then
            If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
                minutes_label.Text = minutes_label.Text - 1
                seconds_label.Text = "59"
            End If
        End If
        If hours_label.Text > "0" Then
            If minutes_label.Text = "0" Then
                If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
                    hours_label.Text = hours_label.Text - 1
                    minutes_label.Text = "59"
                    seconds_label.Text = "59"
                End If
            End If
        End If

    If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
        If minutes_label.Text = "0" Then
            If hours_label.Text = "0" Then
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                MsgBox("Time is up")
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    If Start.Text = "Start" Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Start.Text = "Start"
        MsgBox("TIME'S UP")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why you need to write in button click event then?

Comment: @AshReva the scrpit above is with a button idealy i dont want a button just the countdown.

Comment: @Charlie.P don't forget to tell us what worked for you, friend.

Comment: Add Timer From ToolBox In VS and Set It's property Enabled = true

Answer (score 1):

Use the Form's `LOAD` event.

```
     Private Sub Payroll_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

         Timer1.Start()

     End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you want the form to simulate the `Clicking` of your button, then call the appropriate button click subroutine.

```
       Private Sub Payroll_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

          Button1_Click(sender, e) 

     End Sub
```

In here, `Button1_Click(sender, e)` is the name of the subroutine with the handler to your start button.